# Build URLS from JSON

Tags: javascript, url, uri

I've created a function that can build nested urls like so. I was wondering if there existed a more mainstream library to build urls / uris like this. I'd rather use a standard.

```
utility.urlConstruct({
    "scheme": "https://",
    "domain": "domain.com",
    "path": "/login",
    "query":{
        "user":"thomasreggi",
        "from":utility.urlConstruct({
            "scheme": "https://",
            "domain": "redirect.com",
            "path": "/funstuff",
        }),
    }
});
```

Spits out

> https://domain.com/login?user=thomasreggi&from=https%3A%2F%2Fredirect.com%2Ffunstuff

Comment: I strongly suggest you remove any trailing commas since there are browsers out there that hate them so the last `},` should be `}`

Comment: gotcha, this was an example. I don't wannna use this above code anyway I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Published my module here https://github.com/reggi/schemejs

Comment: @ThomasReggi, thanks for sharing your github repo. I discovered nodejs has it's own `url#parse` method. See **Edit 2** on [my answer to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13506482/184600)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is node's built in [URL library](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html).

Specifically

```
url.format(urlObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does this internally for its AJAX calls. Perhaps there is a way to access the internal functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Al least there are standard conventions:

- the scheme (or protocol) excludes //
- your domain is called host (and can include sub-domains or port)
- path is called pathname
- query is a list of parameters
- you might also need a hash

Then it is pretty straightforward, so no real need for a library. You'll find some libraries out there, like [jsuri](http://code.google.com/p/jsuri/), but their purpose is more to help for parsing than construct (for example to address cross-browser inconsistencies with pathname).

Comment: I wanted to also build `mailto:` schemes. The words schemes and protocol are interchangeable. Path and Query are express.js terms. I've also inculded port, etc. It's not as simple as it looks. JavaScript should have something like this, that everyone uses.

Comment: I think that this needs to be a library, and that those synonyms should be built in alternatives.

Answer (score -2):

[image: Click here, SCHEME.js]

I built Scheme.js to build url's via javascript objects, please feel free to offer any advancements.