# How to extract the host from a URL in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, url

Capture the domain till the ending characters `$, \?, /, :`. I need a regex that captures `example.com` in all of these.

```
example.com:3000
example.com?pass=gas
example.com/
example.com
```

Comment: @macek I built a URL / URI builder for javascript that takes arguments and constructs the URL from an object. I'm looking to create a regular expression that can take a string and create the object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498417/build-urls-from-json

Comment: Published my module here https://github.com/reggi/schemejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reccomend using the [new URL class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) that is now included in most browsers.

```js
var urls = [
  'http://example.com:3000',
  'http://example.com?pass=gas',
  'http://example.com/',
  'http://example.com'
];

urls.forEach(url => {
  const u = new URL(url)
  console.log(u.hostname)
})
```

Answer (score 57):

If you actually have valid URLs, this will work:

```
var urls = [
    'http://example.com:3000',
    'http://example.com?pass=gas',
    'http://example.com/',
    'http://example.com'
];

for (x in urls) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = urls[x];
    console.log(a.hostname);
}

//=> example.com
//=> example.com
//=> example.com
//=> example.com
```

Note, using regex for this kind of thing is silly when the language you're using has other built-in methods.

Other properties available on `A` elements.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "http://example.com:3000/path/to/something?query=string#fragment"

a.protocol   //=> http:
a.hostname   //=> example.com
a.port       //=> 3000
a.pathname   //=> /path/to/something
a.search     //=> ?query=string
a.hash       //=> #fragment
a.host       //=> example.com:3000
```

---

### EDIT #2

Upon further consideration, I looked into the Node.js docs and found this little gem: [**`url#parse`**](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost)

The code above can be rewritten as:

```
var url = require('url');

var urls = [
    'http://example.com:3000',
    'http://example.com?pass=gas',
    'http://example.com/',
    'http://example.com'
];

for (x in urls) {
    console.log(url.parse(urls[x]).hostname);
}

//=> example.com
//=> example.com
//=> example.com
//=> example.com
```

---

### EDIT #1

See the revision history of this post if you'd like to see how to solve this problem using `jsdom` and `nodejs`

Comment: javascript but I would really just like a regex

Comment: This would be great, but I'm working server-side. No doc =[. Might be a way to fake it.

Comment: Have you heard of [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom)? Also, you should've mentioned you were using something like node.js in the tags :P

Comment: I'm on it. Yes. It's late, Tags are gooooood. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasReggi, I added a node.js example. I hope this helps you.

Comment: PHP was ported to JS? that's a scary, scary thought.

Comment: @ThomasReggi, I discovered that nodejs has it's own `url#parse` method. Please see **Edit #2** above.

Comment: +1 for http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost

Comment: Using DOM objects is not JS feature, but DOM binding feature. DOM doesn't exist in many JS environments. Also, it is very slow, and the proper way to perform simple string parsing is EXACTLY using regexps.

Comment: Edit 2 will currently output all the properties of the parsed url, not just the hostname.  You need to target the `.hostname` property.

Comment: hostname includes subdomain

Answer (score 31):

Since you're using node, just use the built-in `url.parse()` method; you want the resulting `hostname` property:

```
var url=require('url');
var urls = [
  'http://example.com:3000',
  'http://example.com?pass=gas',
  'http://example.com/',
  'http://example.com'
];

urls.forEach(function(x) {
  console.log(url.parse(x).hostname);
});
```

Comment: returns `{ pathname: '0', path: '0', href: '0' }
{ pathname: '1', path: '1', href: '1' }
{ pathname: '2', path: '2', href: '2' }
{ pathname: '3', path: '3', href: '3' }`

Comment: Goofed-up test harness (copied from another answer), updated in my answer. Lesson: don't use `for (...in...)` to iterate over arrays.

Comment: it includes subdomain

Comment: @MuhammadUmer subdomain is part of the hostname.

Answer (score 27):

A new challenger has appeared. According to node docs, you can also use

```
   var url = new URL(urlString);
   console.log(url.hostname);
```

https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_the_whatwg_url_api

This seems to be a more current way.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Node `^10` and this is how I extract the hostname from a URL.

```
var url = URL.parse('https://stackoverflow.com/q/13506460/2535178')
console.log(url.hostname)
//=> stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^((?:[a-z0-9-_]+\.)*[a-z0-9-_]+\.?)(?::([0-9]+))?(.*)$/i
```

matches are host, port, path

Comment: Does not work :  s="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506460/how-to-extract-the-host-from-a-url-in-javascript"
s.match(/^((?:[a-z0-9-_]+\.)*[a-z0-9-_]+\.?)(?::([0-9]+))?(.*)$/i) gives the following result :
["http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506460/how-to-extract-the-host-from-a-url-in-javascript", "http", undefined, "://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506460/how-to-extract-the-host-from-a-url-in-javascript"]

Comment: Don't post fake test please. Your results contain string `"http"` as a matched string while the string you say you run regexp on doesn't contain `"http"` substring. You either patched the execution result or source code of your jS virtual machine to achieve this results.
`"stackoverflow.com/questions/13506460/how-to-extract...".match(/^((?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)*[a-z0-9-]+\.?)(?::([0-9]+))?(.*)$/i)` works perfectly fine resulting in `["stackoverflow.com/questions/13506460/how-to-extract...", "stackoverflow.com", undefined, "/questions/13506460/how-to-extract..."]`

Comment: nope, stackoverflow auto cuts the url... Now, please check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/WLGmv/ and let me know if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: Sure thing. You try to use this regexp for the wrong purpose. If you reread the original question, it was not supposed to do what you want. You need to parse URLs with URI scheme, try this: `/^(?:https?:\/\/)?((?:[a-z0-9-_]+\.)*[a-z0-9-_]+\.?)(?::([0-9]+))?(.*)$/i` (works only for http and https or no URI scheme at all). Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/WLGmv/1/